# capybara: find(element) using selector to target a complex attribute name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara

Using cucumber and capybara to test a rails app. Assuming I cannot change the markup, can I use capybara to select the following select in a page full of similar `td`s and `select`s?

```
<td>
  <select name="attributes[ruby][category]">
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Languages</option>
    <option value="3">Communication</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

This seems to fail (I assume because of the nested "[" and "]").

```
find("select[name=attributes[ruby][category]]")
```

Escaping doesn't work either. Thoughts?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can try `find('select', :name => 'attributes[ruby][category]')` or `find_field('attributes[ruby][category]')`.

Comment: maro's first answer no longer works (in Capybara 2.5.0 it gives: `ArgumentError: invalid keys :name, should be one of :count, :minimum, :maximum, :between, :text, :visible, :exact, :match, :wait`) but I upvoted because the use of `find_field` is a perfect solution.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to quote the attribute value:

```
find("select[name='attributes[ruby][category]']")
```

but maro's suggestion of using find_field is a cleaner approach.

Comment: Tried that, but find just returns nil

Answer (score 2):

More generally you can use XPath

```
find(:xpath, "//select[@name='attributes[ruby][category]'")
```

This approach has the advantage that it can be used for any attribute.